# Java proxy using sockets

Tags: java, html, http, http-proxy

I'm experiencing some issues with this code depending on the browser I use, there are URL's displayed correctly in IE but being displayed as plain text in Firefox (for instance www.microsoft.es looks good on IE but not on Firefox).
Don't know what I'm doing wrong here, I think that there's a problem with the headers that I'm using but I'm not sure...

This is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;


public class Server { 


public void startServer() {
    final ExecutorService clientProcessingPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    Runnable serverTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
                while (true) {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    clientProcessingPool.submit(new ClientTask(clientSocket));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverTask);
    serverThread.start();

}

private class ClientTask implements Runnable {
    private Socket clientSocket;

    private ClientTask(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {


            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            String url = null;
            int i=0;
            String [] headers = new String [100];
            String buffer;

            while ((buffer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                headers[i]=buffer;
                i++;

                if(buffer.contains("GET"))
                {
                    String[] splitText = buffer.split(" ");
                    url = splitText[1];
                    }
                if(buffer.contains("POST"))
                {
                    String[] splitText = buffer.split(" ");
                    url = splitText[1];
                    }
                if(buffer.contains("CONNECT"))
                {
                    String[] splitText = buffer.split(" ");
                    url = "https://"+splitText[1];
                    }
                if (buffer.isEmpty()) break;
                }

                    URL u = new URL(url);
                    URLConnection connection = u.openConnection();

                    for (int x=1;x<i-1;x++){
                    if (!headers[x].contains("Accept-Encoding:")){
                        connection.setRequestProperty(headers[x].substring(0, headers[x].indexOf(":")).toString() , headers[x].replace(headers[x].substring(0, headers[x].indexOf(":") +2), "").toString());
                    }
                    }

                    boolean redirect = false;

                    int status = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
                    if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
                        redirect = true;
                    }


                    if (redirect) {

                        String Url = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
                        URL urlloc = new URL(Url);
                        connection = urlloc.openConnection();

                        for (int x=1;x<i-1;x++){

                            if (!headers[x].contains("Accept-Encoding:")){
                                connection.setRequestProperty(headers[x].substring(0, headers[x].indexOf(":")).toString() , headers[x].replace(headers[x].substring(0, headers[x].indexOf(":") +2), "").toString());
                            }
                            }
                    }


                        byte[] chunk = new byte[1024];
                        int bytesRead;
                        InputStream stream;
                        stream = connection.getInputStream();
                        while ((bytesRead = stream.read(chunk)) > 0) {
                            out.write(chunk, 0, bytesRead);
                            out.flush();
                        }


                out.close();
                in.close();
                clientSocket.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } 
    }
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is, but you should use a tool like Wireshark to examine the actual network traffic between the browser and your proxy, and compare it to the network traffic between the browser and the site when you connect to the site directly.

Comment: I don't know, I didn't notice any problems (except for that thing that wasn't a problem that I misunderstood and deleted), but clearly there must be a bug otherwise why would it not work?

Comment: No, I didn't say that. I said, I couldn't find the bug, but maybe there is a bug there somewhere. There probably is. Use Wireshark to investigate the problem.